# Cannot call value of non-function type 'Entry' when using CoreData

Tags: swift, core-data

the function is suppose to find an Entry, or created a new one.
on the last line the compiler complain that "Cannot call value of non-function type 'Entry'".
I watched a stanford class online and this is how the teacher does it, but when i tried it with my project, it won't creat a new entry and set the attribute, what did i do wrong?
Thanks for helping!

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class Entry: NSManagedObject{
class func findOrCreatEntry(matching Entry: Entry, in context: NSManagedObjectContext) throws -> Entry
{
    let request: NSFetchRequest<Entry> = fetchRequest()
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "creatTime = &@", Entry.creatTime! as CVarArg)

    do {
        let matches = try context.fetch(request)
        if matches.count > 0 {
            assert(matches.count == 1, "Entry.findOrCreatEntry -- database inconsistency")
            return matches[0]
        }
    } catch {
        throw error
    }

        let entry = Entry(context: context)
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the last row be `return Entry(context: context)`?

Comment: You are using Entry (with uppercase E) as both the name of the class, and as the name of the parameter in the function call.  I think the compiler might be confusing the two.  In general, class and type names should begin with uppercase, while instances should begin with lowercase characters.

Comment: @pbasdf is correct.  Change to `matching entry: Entry` and that error goes away.

Comment: solved it, Thanks to pbasdf & Philip, Helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You have to return the new created `Entry` instance.

Your method can be written a bit shorter and please name parameter labels lowercased.

```
class func findOrCreatEntry(matching entry: Entry, in context: NSManagedObjectContext) throws -> Entry
{
    let request: NSFetchRequest<Entry> = Entry.fetchRequest()
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "creatTime = %@", entry.creatTime! as CVarArg)

    if let firstMatch = try context.fetch(request).first {
       return firstMatch 
    } else {
       return Entry(context: context)
    }
}
```

What is the goal of this method? The parameter is an **existing** `Entry` instance! Actually the method is only useful if the parameter is just the creation date.

And there was another typo `&@` vs `%@`